# Proof of $P(X=x) = F_X(x) - F_X(x-)$ (Probabilities from CDFs)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Would this be an acceptable proof of $P(X=x) = F_X(x) - F_X(x-)$? Unsure if the explanation to move from $P(X\le x) - P(X<x)$ to $F_X(x) - F_X(x-)$ is valid.

[image]

Comment: I'm also unsure if it's valid... the equations are true but I don't understand how you're justifying them. What is "left limit / continuity"? Also, a bit more nitpicky: "$P(X=x) = P(X\le x) - P(X<x)$" that's true but seems like the kind of thing worth justifying in this solution, assuming it hasn't come up in earlier exercises.

Comment: One justification is that you can let $A_n = \{X\le x-1/n\},$ and then $A_n\uparrow \{X<x\},$ so, $$F(x^-) = \lim_n F(x-1/n) = \lim_n P(A_n) = P(X<x),$$ where we used continuity of measure in the last equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is fine if you formalize it and make sure it's written properly. An example without changing any of your work:

Let $X$ be a random variable with CDF $F_X(x)$, defined such that $F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$. Next, by definition of CDF and left limit continuity, we know that $\mathbb{P}(X < x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}F(x-h) = F(x^-)$. Then, we know that $\mathbb{P}(X = x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) - \mathbb{P}(X < x)$, and by substitution we obtain $\mathbb{P}(X = x) = F_X(x) - F_X(x^-)$, Q.E.D.

Comment: What is "left limit continuity"?